# Bulk update KMZ tags

Tags: qgis, kmz

I have a KMZ folder and I want to update all the tags/KMZs in the folder. I want to add lat lon data to each KMZ tag. Currently I'm adding it one by one but this would take too long. How would I bulk update the tags. This would also have to be automated because each KMZ has its own lat lon coordinates.

Comment: You can't really edit kmz files in QGIS, at least not adding attributes. What do you need it for? Would it be OK to export the data another format like Geopackage? There, you can add lon lat coordinates with Fieldcalculator using `$x` and `$y` respectively (as long as you keep the layer's CRS in `EPSG:4326`).

Comment: in short I need a way to add lat lon to kmz tags/kmz script all at once in google earth not qgis. So some kind of automation that adds lat lon to my kmz table/tag

Comment: So if you don't want to do it in QGIS, I would delete the qgis tag